# remove underline with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a link like:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" title=""> <img src="stack.png" alt="" title="" /> stackoverflow </a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a { text-decoration: underline}
```

I want to remove the `underline` from the image.

I tried:

```
a img {text-decoration:none}
```

But it not works.

BS: 
I can do that if I added a `display:block` to `img` but that can cause a damage for the rest of the site, also I won't add a specific class for this section.

Could I do that with jQuery?

Comment: You want to use a {text-decoration: none}

Comment: Trying to replicate your code, I am not getting any underline on my image. Is there another style interfering with this?

Comment: @John Strickler: I want my links to be underlined

Comment: @Francis Gilbert maybe you are using a reset or something. And No I have just one css file with one `a` and `img` attributes

Comment: No, just exactly as you have said above with the obvious <head> etc.

Comment: The issue is that "text-decoration: underline" underlines everything wrapped in an A tag. He doesn't want images inside A tags to be underlined.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should do this with CSS.

You could add an inline style to that link:

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"> <img src=...etc /> stackoverflow </a>
```

Or you could add a class to that link:

```
<a href="#" title="" class="img"> <img src=...etc. /> stackoverflow </a>

In your css...

a.img {text-decoration:none;}
```

**EDIT:**

If you cannot alter the `html`, then use jQuery:

```
$('a img').parent().css('textDecoration','none')
```

(This is similar to what is above, but targets the parent of the `img` -- that is the `a` -- and then changes the style appropriately.)

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/vM55K/

**EDIT 2:**

If that is the only `child` element in an `a`, you could use this:

```
 $('a').children().css('textDecoration','none')
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/vM55K/1/

Comment: can't edit the HTML code. I can only add a jquery or css code

Comment: gennaro: Thanks but I want the link `stackoverflow` to be underlined

Comment: I think this might be it @MiniNaim.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you.

```
$('a img').css('text-decoration','none')
```

Comment: he wrote that already tried it adding the proper css but it doesn't work. It doesn't work with jQuery also http://jsfiddle.net/XFVMQ/1/

Comment: Put it inside a ready function and change 'a img' to 'a' - see new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XFVMQ/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/XFVMQ/5/

Comment: What about $('a img').css('float', 'left') ?

Comment: @steve Hansell: thank you, but I can't add a `float` to the image

Comment: @John Strickler It works but the links are without the underline too :)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

$("img[src="stack.png"]).css("text-decoration","none");

**Edit

Is your issue how to add styles to the specific element without effecting the rest of the DOM? Or is your issue what styles you need to set to specifically get rid of the underlines?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$("a img").parentsUntil("a").css("text-decoration","none");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a specificity problem?

Try removing borders and all decoration using a more specific CSS selector:

```
a > img {
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried many solutions with CSS before writing my question. It not works.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use CSS: `a img {border: none}` or you could try setting the image to `display: inline-block`

Comment: +1 - The image shouldn't have an underline, per se, but it might have a border, depending on the browser defaults.

Comment: As I said before: the solution is to add a `display:block` to the `img` but that will cause a damage

Comment: using inline-block will likely prevent some of the 'damage' but your best bet is to remove the border. As @FishBasketGordo mentioned above, images don't really have underlines, they have borders. setting the border to 'none' or '0px' should solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to seperate the anchor for `img` and for text. Try the following markup:

```
<a href="#" title=""><img src="stack.png" alt="" title="" /></a><a href="#" title="">stackoverflow </a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XFVMQ/

---

A second solution, according my comment, is to add `margin-bottom:-3px` for `a img`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XFVMQ/

---

A third solution to add `outline: 3px solid white;` for `a img` this will override the underline, change it to the proper color.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XFVMQ/6/

Comment: I can't do that because I run a PHP script, so I can't edit or generate the code :)

Comment: @MiniNaim then the only "dirty" method I can think is to add `a img {margin-bottom:-3px}`. This will move the underlinewith result to be covered by the image. http://jsfiddle.net/XFVMQ/3/